# Identifying stationary points

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

How do we find stationary points of $f(x) = x^3-3x^2$ ?

I take the derivative and set it equal to $0$ and solve and I get:

$f'(x) = 3x^2-6x$ , putting it equal to zero, I have: $3x(x-3)=0$ which gives $x=0$ and $x=3$.
Now, while $(0,0)$ is both an $x$-intercept and a stationary point, $x=3$ is an $x$-intercept but not a stationary point and, looking at the graph of the function, I know that there is another stationary point at $x=2$. **How do we get this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$3x^2-6x = 3x(x-2) \neq 3x(x-3)$$

Comment: got confused...what a shame of question I wrote. Thank you!:)

Comment: @Alwayslearning: Keep learning ;-)

Comment: yes, but that's not learning...it was distraction :(